# Colored points are not displayed in ggplot2 dumbbell plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to create a dumbbell plot with ggplot2 but the when I try to decorate with colored points using geom_dumbbell I cannot display them. I followed the method [here](https://rpubs.com/ageek/ggplot-adv-part2)

```
TMA_total <- tribble(
  ~'TMA', ~'Younger siblings', ~'Older siblings',
  "Present",       18.72,           35.98,
  "Preterite",     55.07,           41.08,
  "Imperfect",     24.89,           18.98,
  "Subjunctive",  0.44,             1.70, 
  "Other",        0.88,             2.22
) 

# Geom dumbbell plot
TMA_total$TMA <- factor(TMA_total$TMA, levels = as.character(TMA_total$TMA))


# Geom dumbbell plot
ggplot(TMA_total, aes(x=`Younger siblings`, xend=`Older siblings`, y=TMA)) + 
  #create a thick line between x and xend instead of using defaut 
  #provided by geom_dubbell
  geom_segment(aes(x=`Younger siblings`, 
                   xend=`Older siblings`, 
                   y=TMA, 
                   yend=TMA), 
               color="#b2b2b2", size=1.5)
  geom_dumbbell(color="light blue", 
                size_x=3.5, 
                size_xend = 3.5,
                #Note: there is no US:'color' for UK:'colour' 
                # in geom_dumbbel unlike standard geoms in ggplot()
                colour_x="#edae52", 
                colour_xend = "#9fb059")
```

What I get:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: I think you're missing a `+` between `geom_segment` and `geom_dumbbell`

Comment: oh yes......u re right